# WCF; Calling the callback of a service in another WCF service raises cast error

Tags: c#, wcf

I have a very simple callback WCF service which I want to call it from another WCF service. I followed [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/samples/design-patterns-list-based-publish-subscribe) sample to keep things simple as possible. When I call `subscribe` method the line:

```
callback = OperationContext.Current.GetCallbackChannel<ICommunicationCallback>();
```

gives error:

```
System.InvalidCastException: 'Unable to cast object of type 'System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel' to type 'QCWCFService.ICommunicationCallback'.'
```

The caller WCF service is like below:

```
{
    [ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.PerCall,
         ConcurrencyMode = ConcurrencyMode.Multiple)]
    public class QCService : IQCService
    {

        
        private readonly ICommunicationService _communicationService;
        public QCService(ICommunicationService communicationService)
        {
            _communicationService = communicationService;
        }
        public void SubscribeAndPublish()
        {
            try
            {
                
                _communicationService.Subscribe();
                _communicationService.PublishPriceChange("item 1", 1, 0.4);
                return UserAction;
            }
            catch (SocketException ex)
            {
                return null;
                throw;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return null;
                throw;
            }

        }
    }
}
```

And the `web.config` is as follow:

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <client>
        <endpoint address="" binding="wsDualHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="CommunicationConsumerBinding" contract="ProductionSetWCFService.ICommunicationService" />
    </client>
    <bindings>
        <basicHttpBinding>
            <binding name="QCConsumerBinding" closeTimeout="00:10:00" openTimeout="00:10:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:10:00" allowCookies="false" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard" maxBufferSize="50000000" maxBufferPoolSize="5242880" maxReceivedMessageSize="50000000" messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Buffered" useDefaultWebProxy="true">
                <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
                <security mode="None">
                    <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None" realm="" />
                    <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
                </security>
            </binding>
        </basicHttpBinding>
        <wsDualHttpBinding>
            <binding name="CommunicationConsumerBinding" closeTimeout="00:10:00" openTimeout="00:10:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:10:00"  bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"  maxBufferPoolSize="5242880" maxReceivedMessageSize="50000000" messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8"  useDefaultWebProxy="true">
                <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
                <reliableSession inactivityTimeout="00:30:00"/>

                <security mode="None"/>
            </binding>
        </wsDualHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <services>      
        <service name="QCWCFService.QCService">
            <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="QCConsumerBinding" contract="QCWCFService.IQCService" >

            </endpoint>
            <host>
                <baseAddresses>
                    <add baseAddress="http://localhost:55915/QCService" />
                </baseAddresses>
            </host>
        </service>
        <service name="QCWCFService.CommunicationService">
            <endpoint address="" binding="wsDualHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="CommunicationConsumerBinding" contract="ProductionSetWCFService.ICommunicationService" />
            <host>
                <baseAddresses>
                    <add baseAddress="http://localhost:55915/CommunicationService" />
                </baseAddresses>
            </host>
        </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
        <serviceBehaviors>
            <behavior>
                <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the values below to false before deployment -->
                <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
                <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
                <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
                <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483647" />
            </behavior>
        </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
</system.serviceModel>
```

I followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52583955/call-one-wcf-service-from-another-wcf-service-endpoint-error) answer and added `<client>` tag but again got the same error.

Comment: Use the duplex binding NetTcpBinding to connect to WCF services (Note: you cannot use simplex basicHttpBinding)